# Jenkins API : issues with tree filter in java

Tags: java, jenkins, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to fetch all job names by using below code

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://myjenkins/api/json?depth=1&tree=jobs[name,jobs[name]]")
     try(CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
          try(CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet)){
               int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
               if (statusCode == 200) {
                     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                     String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                     System.out.println(json)
               }
          }
}
```

The above code is not returning any json response (just an empty array []), but if I remove tree query in the url (http://myjenkins/api/json?depth=1), then I get json response with all jobs.

Why the query with filter is not returning any results ?. Is something wrong with HttpClient or jenkins api.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: First things first: you can do `try (Foo foo = ...; Bar bar = ...;) { /* whatever */ }` -- the try-with-resources statement will handle this correctly. No need for two try-with-resources here. See [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10mD-_M_fXOU3LOP5hmqVTlcJhgn5FUCwTLIdor2Z4qM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The _depth_ parameter is unnecessary with the _tree_ filter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just trying out that url in a browser. I tried it against my instance of jenkins, and it worked fine. 
Also, the second parameter in the tree query seems unnecessary - even this url returns the job names - 
http://myjenkins/api/json?depth=1&tree=jobs[name]

Comment: There are some cases where nested jobs in the query reveals more data, perhaps it's related to the Folders plugin. Compare `https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/api/json?tree=jobs[name]&pretty=true` and `https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/api/json?tree=jobs[name,jobs[name]]&pretty=true`, and notice the _danielbeck_ job has nested jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things ..

1) I tried it my browser and all queries worked well but not through java code. The reason is, in browser am already signed in (git oauth) and all queries are working where as in java am getting empty array since jenkins authorization set to not read jobs for anonymus (Stupid of me not check this before).

2) Once proper permissions are set I still had an issue with URI encoding, then I used URI builder

```
 URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("http").setHost(jenkinsHost)
            .setPath("/api/json")
            .setParameter("depth", "1").setParameter("tree", "jobs[name,jobs[name]]")
            .build()
```

everything works now.